# Drop down list (Asp.net web forms) not getting populated with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have jQuery call to get the data and a dropdown list on the UI, which is not populating the data.
I have tried many ways, commented is the code I used.
Let me know if I did something wrong in the code.

```html
var questionData;
var optionData;

$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'coaching-assessment-tool.aspx/GetCATQuestionAndOptions',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {            
            questionData = data.d[0];
            optionData = data.d[1];           
            console.log(questionData[0].QuestionText);
            console.log("Question Data", questionData);
            console.log("Option Data", optionData);
            //Questions
            document.getElementById('firstQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[0].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('secondQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[1].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('thirdQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[2].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('fourthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[3].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('fifthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[4].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('sixthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[5].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('seventhQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[6].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('eighthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[7].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('ninthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[8].QuestionText;
            document.getElementById('tenthQuestion').innerHTML = questionData[9].QuestionText;
            //Responses
            //var ddlFirstResponse = document.getElementById('#ddlFirstResponse');
            //ddlFirstResponse.empty();
            $(function () {
                $('#ddlFirstResponse').append($("<option></option>").val('').html(''));
                $.each(optionData, function (key, value) {
                    //console.log('option: ' + value.OptionText + ' | id: ' + value.OptionId);
                    //$('#ddlFirstResponse').append($("<option></option>").val(value.OptionId).html(value.OptionText));
                    $("#ddlFirstResponse").append("<option value='" + value.OptionId + "'>" + value.OptionText + "</option>");
                });
            });            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Error retrieving data. Please contact support.');
        }        
    });
    
});


<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFirstResponse" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: 'optionData ' has the data and is printing to the console.log.

Comment: What's the JSON, what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I received response a bit late, I did trial and error, and finally made it to work.
Here is the code changes I made to make it work.

```html
var ddlFirstResponse = **$("[id*=ddlFirstResponse]");**            
            ddlFirstResponse.empty();
            $(function () {
                ddlFirstResponse.append($("<option></option>").val('').html('-- Select value --'));
                $.each(industryOptionData, function (key, value) {
                    //console.log('option: ' + value.OptionText + ' | id: ' + value.OptionId);
                    ddlFirstResponse.append($("<option></option>").val(value.OptionId).html(value.OptionText));
                    //ddlFirstResponse.append("<option value='" + value.OptionId + "'>" + value.OptionText + "</option>");
                });
            });
```

//var ddlFirstResponse = document.getElementById('ddlFirstResponse'); --> Failed
var ddlFirstResponse = $("[id*=ddlFirstResponse]"); --> worked

Answer (score 0):

Your data return handler is a bit off when the returned data is acquired, you can do the following to alleviate that:

```
function (data, status) {
    var json = data;
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    var opt = null;
    $("#targetIDOfControl").empty();

    for (i = 0; i < obj.People.length; i++) {
        if (i < obj.People.length) {
            opt = null;
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            document.getElementById("targetIDOfControl").options.add(opt);

            opt.text = obj.People[i].Name;
            opt.value = obj.People[i].ID;
        }
    }
```

The above example creates an option then sets its text and values. Then replicates more options depending on the amount of indexes in the JSON array returned.

Comment: Why `JSON.parse()`? `data` should already be parsed, per [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: **Should** however I've had bugs where it will refuse to operate as parsed JSON unless I specifically call this - I've done it since and not had the same errors.

Comment: For the OP, I'd recommend something like this: `if (typeof data === 'string') { data = JSON.parse(data); }`. `JSON.parse` will throw a SyntaxError if you pass an already-parsed object.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, I appreciate it.